# How to find the minimum connectors to connect selected vertices (subset of vertices)

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

suppose that i have a un-directed graph with 10 vertices and 24 edges which connects with each other, as an example if i give an input like this (this is not the actual one, actual one is 10*10)

```
int graph[][] = new int[][]{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                            {0, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0},
                            {0, 2, 0, 3, 8, 5},
                            {0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7},
                            {0, 6, 8, 0, 0, 9},
                            {0, 0, 5, 7, 9, 0}};
```

so i want to find the ***minimum connectors in order to connect specific vertices*** 
*ex: vertices 0,2,4*. currently i applied the prims algorithm in order to get the minimum connectors through out all the edges of the graph, but as i don't want all the edges to be included in my MST i need some help achieving this.

- I can't remove the edges what i don't want in the beginning because it will disconnect the graph

please help.

Comment: From Wikipedia: 
"A minimum spanning tree (MST) or minimum weight spanning tree is a subset of the edges of a connected, edge-weighted undirected graph that connects all the vertices together, without any cycles and with the minimum possible total edge weight.". So as you can see a MST is by definition connecting all the vertices together. If you only want to connect a part of the graph it sounds like you're looking for something like a shortest path algorithm. Check out Dijkstra's alogorithm or A*, they might offer what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, but how is a 6x6 matrix as definition of 10 vertices and 24 edges?

Comment: @JonckvanderKogel thanks for the reply, what i actually need is the the least amount of edges in-order to connect a subset of nodes in the graph, but in the shortest path algorithm it only finds the shortest path between 2 vertices. but i need the  minimum vertices (with the weight) in order to connect some vertices which are also in the graph.

Comment: @Andreas its actually an example not the actual dataset  :D

Comment: Perhaps if you edit the question and show *example* inputs and outputs, your question might be better understood.

Comment: So saying "10 vertices and 24 edges" and showing a 6x6 matrix is just to make sure we're confused? What is that matrix supposed to show? How should it be interpreted?

Comment: @Andreas its corrected now

Comment: So that is 6 vertices and 7 undirected edges? Why not just say that in the question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 6 vertices and 7 undirected weighted edges:

```
 1 ←→ 2 (w=2)
 1 ←→ 4 (w=6)
 2 ←→ 3 (w=3)
 2 ←→ 4 (w=8)
 2 ←→ 5 (w=5)
 3 ←→ 5 (w=7)
 4 ←→ 5 (w=9)
```

You need to connect vertices 0, 2, and 4, so you build a new graph with those 3 vertices, and find the **shortest paths** between them.

```
 0 ←→ 2 (no edge)
 0 ←→ 4 (no edge)
 2 ←→ 4 (w=8)
```

That of course cannot be done, since there are no edges to vertex 0.

So let's try vertices 1, 3, and 5 instead:

```
 1 ←→ 3 (w=5, 1 ←→ 2 ←→ 3)
 1 ←→ 5 (w=7, 1 ←→ 2 ←→ 5)
 3 ←→ 5 (w=7, 3 ←→ 5)
```

Now apply a minimum spanning tree (MST) to that:

```
 1 ←→ 3 ←→ 5 (w=12)
```

Expanding back to original graph:

```
 1 ←→ 2 ←→ 3 ←→ 5 (w=12)
```